# Headphones Issue

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones, audio-jack

I got a new computer several months ago (MSI Ghost Pro GS60) and installed Ubuntu 16.04 on it. The whole time I've been using it, I've had some issues with the headphones that I haven't been able to resolve.

The issue is multifaceted. The main problem is that the audio doesn't automatically switch to the headphones when they are plugged in. 
What happens instead is that the audio comes from both the computer speakers and the headphones, but while the speaker volume is adjustable, the headphones are blaring very loudly and don't respond to volume controls.

I can manually go into the sound settings and select the Digital Output (S/PDIF) option, but I would like for this to happen automatically.

I also don't think that the headphones jack is actually S-PDIF. It's just a standard 3.5 mm, but I don't know if that's a related problem or not.

The output of

```
lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 audio
```

is

```
00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H HD Audio [8086:a170] (rev 31)
Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Sunrise Point-H HD Audio [1462:1158]
Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

Answer (score 0):

The intel-hda sound driver is used for lots of different implementations by different manufacturers. They don't always connect the pins on the chip the same way. This sounds like your issue and to solve it you will need to find the module options to configure it .

Here's a list of the currently supported models

```
http://git.alsa-project.org/?p=alsa-kernel.git;a=blob;f=Documentation/sound/alsa/HD-Audio-Models.txt;hb=HEAD
```

to change the model the intel-hda driver users by editing 
the options line for it in /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf

```
options snd-hda-intel model=
```

Alternatively you can use hda-jack-retask to reassign the ports as discussed here

```
http://voices.canonical.com/david.henningsson/2011/11/29/turn-your-mic-jack-into-a-headphone-jack/
```

Here's a guide to using them

```
http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Help_To_Debug_Intel_HDA
```

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure I know enough to make use of that. Thanks for the info, though.
Could it be an issue with the Realtek codec?

Comment: i've added some more info that should explain that, let me know if its not working for you

Comment: Well, I don't see the model of my computer to use with alsa-base.conf, and I tried a few which looked like they might be similar, but they didn't work.
I've also tried using hdajackretask after installing alsa-tools-gui, but every time I try to reassign a pin, I get a message like

tee: /sys/class/sound/hwC0D0/reconfig: Device or resource busy

Comment: if something is busy run 'lsof /path/to/file' and you will get a list of processes that have it open

Comment: If I try `lsof /sys/class/sound/hwC0D0/reconfig`, I get
`lsof: WARNING: can't stat() tracefs file system /sys/kernel/debug/tracing
      Output information may be incomplete`

If I try `sudo lsof /sys/class/sound/hwC0D0/reconfig`, I get 
`lsof: WARNING: can't stat() tracefs file system /sys/kernel/debug/tracing
      Output information may be incomplete.`